# Why is the output different with %f argument?

Tags: c

```
int a=3.14*150;
printf("%d",a);
return 0;
```

This works fine, output is 471

```
int a=3.14*150;
printf("%f",a);
return 0;
```

but now the output is -0.104279
I thought int will be promoted to float
but output is totally different
I am using gcc 4.7.2 ubuntu 12.10

Comment: No, it won't be promoted. Try `float f=a; printf("%f",f);`

Comment: sizeof(int) is 4 Byte and sizeof(float) also 4 byte. 
But if you try to printf your int as float, the part of your bits stands on decimal places. I think you could shift your bytes left two times to see the right value as float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour to use wrong conversion specifier for `printf`. (It's true of `scanf` as well).

Now, the `%f` conversion specifier means that the bits of the `int` variable `a` will be interpreted as a floating point value. Floating-point values are generally implemented as per [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) though this is not mandated by the standard. This explains why your output is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` doesn't inspect element types - it assumes you're being honest and that you're actually passing what you say you're going to pass. It's undefined behavior printing types with specifiers that don't match.

Answer (score 0):

The sizes differ, so this is undefined behavior. There can't be any promotion based on information in the format string, that's not how the language works. The `printf()` function is just a function.